# Web Apps - Update Application Settings - format of json

Tags: azure

I am trying to programmatically update an Azure functions appsettings via a REST call but am unable to figure out or find an example of the JSON request required.

I have initiated the call, done the authentication, but can't figure out the structure of the JSON required.

I have used the test page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/updateapplicationsettings#code-try-0

The following is the code to update the config:

```
private static async Task<string> UpdateConfig(string token, string subscriptionId, string RGName, string siteName, string config)
        {

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            string URL = $"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{RGName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{siteName}/config/appsettings?api-version=2016-08-01";
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

            var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(config);
            var content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PutAsync(URL, content);

            return response.StatusCode.ToString();
        }
```

Attempts so far have met with "BadRequest - SiteAppSettings object is not present in the request body", from this I assume I do not have the JSON correct.

Does anyone have an example of the JSON to post or further pointers where I may be able to get the shape of the request please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause your different Applications have different settings.So if you don't know the Json format, you could use [List Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listapplicationsettings) to get the Application details Json string, then change the settings you want to update.

I add the `TestSetting` in my Application Setting with Postman.

Body

```
{
  "id": "subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resource group}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{WebAppName}/config/appsettings",
  "name": "appsettings",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
  "location": "South Central US",
  "tags": {
    "hidden-related:/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{groupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/tomfreePlan": "empty"
  },
  "properties": {
    "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION": "8.11.1",
    "TestSetting": "test"
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this - this pointed to exactly where I needed to be. In my solution I am retrieving the config contents via a REST call, from here I will add or modify a property, from your example above I identified that the response contained multiple "/" characters which threw off the [link](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{RGName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{siteName}/config/appsettings?api-version=2016-08-01) endpoint.